# Linking google forms to master & children spreadsheets with automatic updates

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have a two-part question about master/child relationships in workbooks. I have beginner experience with writing code for excel & google spreadsheets so any extra detail would be truly appreciated.

Here is what I'm trying to achieve:

I want to make a google form to collect a set of data for (potentially 100's of people). The option to make changes to the form after submission will be enabled, so the data flow will be pretty dynamic. I've gotten as far as setting this up and creating the master spreadsheet where I can view all of the responses. But there's too much information in one spreadsheet and I'd like to make some child-workbooks to simplify the viewable data for various needs. So here are my questions:

1) How would I write the script to create a child worksheet from the master worksheet with these conditions: on run create a new worksheet called i.e "Child 1-Basic Info", delete all the columns  and shift left with the exception of the ones I explicitly want to keep (based on the cell value) i.e "Name", "Age" & "Interests". Bear in mind I would want to eventually create multiple children workbooks, but basically do the same job each time. Just different column parameters i.e "Child 2-Education Info".

2) Along with this, I want to make sure that these children will be automatically updated every time someone submits a new response from my form or updates one they have already submitted. Essentially, the goal is to have any changes in the master ripple into all of the children. Also keep in mind that every time someone submits a new form, the row numbers will change. So the children will need to also recognize this change and update accordingly.

Thank you all in advanced!

Answer (score 1):

With the `QUERY()` function, you can have secondary sheets that will dynamically update, with no need to use scripts at all. See more [here](http://support.google.com/drive/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1388882).

Here's an example, a spreadsheet with rows of form-submitted data:

[image]

On a secondary sheet in the same spreadsheet, cell A1 contains a query formula that selects only the columns you asked for, "Name, Age, and Interests".

[image]

Every new form submission or update will result in recalculation of the query, so it will be kept up-to-date with no further intervention.